# is it possible to read a file without saving it in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I need to submit a file via a multipart API POST request to `https://files.stripe.com/v1/files`, but I do not want this file to be saved to my own database.

[This class](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/stripe/Stripe/File) in the stripe gem implies that I would write some code that looks like:

```
Stripe::File.create({
 file: File.new("/path/to/a/file.jpg"),
 purpose: 'dispute_evidence',
})
```

But for some reason, doing this through params isn't working. My form does this:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: :stripe_file_upload, multipart: true do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :drivers_license_front, "Front of driver's license" %>
 <%= f.file_field :drivers_license_front %>

 <%= f.submit "Upload", data: { disable: true } %>
<% end %>
```

And then the controller action does this:

```
def stripe_file_upload
 file = params[:user][:drivers_license_front]
 Stripe::File.create(
  { purpose: 'identity_document',
   file: file.tempfile },
  { stripe_account: current_user.stripe_user_id }
 )
 puts "file uploaded"
 redirect_to whatever_path
end
```

In case it's helpful, my params output looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NGcXcLnY6mGGyR0SDJNj3UGSzaGrie5TrCv0vGEeasXFhXFtU6eHK10Sbr3MW5Pnax3YjDiNfo9LUi9DEwMA2g==", "user"=>{"drivers_license_front"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb8801431e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0p/3xq9qs1x6mv555tnlt6v9_p80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190902-38824-u77acs.png>, @original_filename="is.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[drivers_license_front]\"; filename=\"is.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
```

The terminal output from this puts the "file uploaded" message, but then if I go check the list of files I've uploaded to Stripe, the image is absent. I have the Stripe API key sent in my config, so I leave that part out from the code sample.

Weirdly, I can open a url like in [this example](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/710#issuecomment-444870324), and submit to Stripe in my console. This works perfectly. The API returns the appropriate JSON response, and the image shows up in the call to `Stripe::File.list`.

Why does it work in console, but not through params? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found this in their docs about how to uplaod a file to handle identity verification. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#uploading-a-file

Comment: You need to authenticate to Stripe API using your secret key and you don't want to store it in your frontend code, this is why it is needed to do it through your server

Comment: Thanks for the replies! What I'm looking for is a hand-holding sort of answer about structure. "You need to do this in your model, this in your controller, and this in your view." The code that I provided is from the Stripe docs, and I already know how to authenticate with my secret key.

Comment: @VincentRolea I already authenticated to stripe with my secret key.  when you say that i don't want to store it in my frontend code, does that mean i DON'T want to write it to `Tempfile`?

Comment: Not saving the file to disk means you need to receive the whole file then send it to a third party API in the same controller action. This doubles the processing time for this request. And if something fails, you have no way to retry the post to Stripe.

Comment: But if you really want to do it, you should be able to pass `params[:file]` directly to `Stripe::File.create(file: params[:file])` in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to authenticate to the API in order to submit files to Stripe, and it can only happen server-side, since you don't want to store your credentials in your frontend code.

In order to submit a file without saving it, a solution would be to have a controller action taking the submitted file, upload it to the Stripe server and redirecting to whatever route you need:

```
# Init Stripe client

Stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

# Controller

def stripe_file_upload 
  file = params[:file]
  Stripe::File.create({
    file: file.tempfile,
    purpose: 'dispute_evidence'
  })
  redirect_to my_custom_path
end

# View

<h1>My Form</h1>

<%= form_tag stripe_file_upload_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file, class: "file-input" %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent! I did end up trying to do something a little bit like what you are suggesting, but it still does not work. The file does not upload to Stripe when submitted through a form, but it does upload when done manually through my console. I've updated my question with new code.

Comment: Do you have any error rails-side? Could you check the Stripe logs as well so we can see what goes wrong?

Comment: I don't have any errors that I can see rails-side. Thanks for reminding me about Stripe logs! Very helpful. I see from these logs that the requests are not going through at all. Hm..